# Unresolved java.net.http classes while running maven clean install

Tags: java, maven, http

I am using java.net.http classes like HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpResponse in my project. Everything is working perfectly fine when I am building the project using Eclipse but when I am trying to execute the command mvn clean install, its unable to find the java.net.http package at all and throwing error for all the classes under this package.

`The import java.net.http.HttpClient cannot be resolved`

The possibility of using older version of java is ruled out as I am using JDK 11.0.7 both in Eclipse and command prompt (powershell). I have also tried listing all the modules in command prompt and I can see `java.net.http@11.0.7`

In my pom.xml I have the enforcement for java version 11 or above like below

``

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.enforcer.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-java</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <version>[11,)</version>
                                    <message>Building requires Java 11 or later</message>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                                    <message>Building requires at least Maven 3.5.0</message>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

``

Also the result of `mvn -version` is  `Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f) Maven home: C:\mvn\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\.. Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you run `mvn —version`?

Comment: Show your Pom.xml

Comment: @BoristheSpider mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\mvn\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Answer (score 1):

> The possibility of using older version of java is ruled out as I am using JDK 11.0.7

Either you didn't properly rule it out, or your java installation is corrupted. That last option is so exotic, it seems vastly more likely you messed up on the exclusionary process.

Note that `mvn clean install` does not neccessarily use the `javac` that is on your path. It'll use what you asked for, and in addition, may well tell that `javac` to use a different definition of which java library is to be assumed available at runtime.

So, doublecheck your maven settings. [Check this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-java-version) so you know what to look for / if there is no java target release (or old-style, source+target) in the pom, now you know what to add.

Comment: I ran mvn - version and there also I can see the java version as 11.0.7 only.

Comment: mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\mvn\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: That merely lists the java that maven runs on. It doesn't list the java used to compile; which one is chosen depends on your pom file, hence why `-version` couldn't possibly tell you. Click the link and read it.